# How to fetch data from event's resource and display on week view in React-Big-Calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am trying to add custom data for month, week and day view. I created custom event file where I separate date and date time for week's event.

I am able to display data if I export event file like this

```
export default [
  {
    progress: '80',
    title: 'streak minus one',
    end: new Date(2022, 2, 21, 10, 8, 0),
    start: new Date(2022, 2, 21, 10, 0, 0),
    resource: {
      month: {
        status: true,
        progress: 80
      }
    }
  },
  {
    progress: '80',
    title: 'streak minus one',
    end: new Date(2022, 2, 21, 10, 19, 0),
    start: new Date(2022, 2, 21, 10, 9, 0),
    resource: {
      month: {
        status: true,
        progress: 80
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But not like this

```
export default [
  {
    title: 'streak minus one',
    end: new Date(2022, 2, 21),
    start: new Date(2022, 2, 21),
    resource: {
      month: {
        progress: 70
      },
      week: [
        {
          endDateTime: new Date(2022, 2, 21, 10, 8, 0),
          startDateTime: new Date(2022, 2, 21, 10, 0, 0)
        },
        {
          endDateTime: new Date(2022, 2, 21, 10, 19, 0),
          startDateTime: new Date(2022, 2, 21, 10, 9, 0)
        },
        {
          endDateTime: new Date(2022, 2, 21, 10, 26, 0),
          startDateTime: new Date(2022, 2, 21, 10, 19, 0)
        },
        {
          endDateTime: new Date(2022, 2, 21, 10, 33, 0),
          startDateTime: new Date(2022, 2, 21, 10, 26, 0)
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    title: 'second event',
    end: new Date(2022, 2, 23),
    start: new Date(2022, 2, 23),
    resource: {
      month: {
        status: true,
        progress: 45
      },
      week: [
        {
          endDateTime: new Date(2022, 2, 22, 10, 15, 0),
          startDateTime: new Date(2022, 2, 22, 10, 0, 0)
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

How to display events by fetching it from resource on Week View in React-big-calendar

Answer (score 0):

React-Big-Calendar expects the `events` individual 'event' data structures to be consistent, and uses the same data 'accessors' (`startAccessor`, `endAccessor`, `titleAccessor`) in all views. You can use `onRangeChange` to reload your `events`, but it would still expect the data structures to be the same.